# How to synchronize a mongo with elasticsearch

Tags: database, mongodb, elasticsearch

I have database MongoDB and i want to synchronize with the elastic search for search data please help me for the best way

> How to synchronize a mongo with elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [mongo-connector](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20ElasticSearch), it can replicate data from a MongoDB database to an Elasticsearch index.